# Selenium (Python) is having issues finding and interacting with a button that has formmethod="get" in it

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I am attempting to click a delete button but Selenium does not locate it even though a save button next to it is completely intractable. The only difference is the delete button has this in the html

```
<input type="submit" name="action[deletecheck]" class="SPSubmitRequest disabledsubmit" formmethod="get" value="Delete">
```

anyone run into this issue?

The selenium error is "no such element: Unable to locate element

Python code

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="SPSubmitRequest disabledsubmit"]').click()
```

Comment: Please add your Python code and the HTML of the button. The more information we have, the easier it will be to help you.

Comment: Have you verified the xpath you're using is correct and is able to identify with element node? You can use browser console (`$x(your_xpath)`) to check this or use any plugin like SelectorsHub to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need apply `Explicit waits` and try different `xpath`.

Apply Wait like below and try:

```
# Imports Required
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

deletebutton = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@class="SPSubmitRequest disabledsubmit"]')))
deletebutton.click()
```

Try below xpaths too

```
//input[@value='Delete']
//input[@name='action[deletecheck]']
//input[@name='action[deletecheck]' and @value='Delete']
```

Note that the `xpath` should `highlight` the `Element` in the `DOM` and it should be unique (1/1)

Comment: Thank you! It ended up being I was not in the "active" tab

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer was about as simple as they come... I wasn't in the active tab.The following code fixed it instantly

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])
```